# MAMP no inicia servidores

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache, localhost

He instalado MAMP para practicar en localhost con una web que estoy haciendo pero no inicia ni el servidor de Apache ni MySQL. No me da ningún error ni nada, simplemente no inician. He probado a cambiar los puertos como dicen por ahí, la versión php, de las cuales sólo puedo elegir 8.0.1 y 8.1.0 pero nada. Al abrir el programa se queda sin hacer nada. Lo he desinstalado y reinstalado y no hay manera.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente el problema se resolvió instalando la versión 4.2 de MAMP, la cual trabaja con versiones inferiores a php 8.0.
En la versión 5.0 de MAMP, vienen disponibles versiones de php superiores a 8.0 y esto es lo que impedía iniciar servidores.